# DRY:er way of conditionally applying classes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm going through an array to apply different classes based on a state that is set externally. This is how I do it now, but I feel like i'm repeating myself a lot. Is there a DRYer way to do it? The classnames could be something else if that helps.

```
var children2 = Array.from(wrapper.children);
var s = state.state;
children2.forEach((child, i) => {
    var classes = [];
    child.classList.remove('active', 'before', 'previous', 'next', 'after');
    if(i < s) { classes.push('before'); };
    if(i > s) { classes.push('after');  };
    if(i === s) { classes.push('active') }
    if(i === s - 1) { classes.push('previous') }
    if (i === s + 1) { classes.push('next') }
    child.classList.add(...classes)
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

> `toggle( String [, force] )`
>
> When only one argument is present: Toggle class value; i.e., if class exists then remove it and return false, if not, then add it and
>   return true.
>
> When a second argument is present: If the second argument evaluates to true, add specified class value, and if it evaluates to
>   false, remove it.

For example like this:

```
let classes = child.classList;
classes.toggle('before', i < s);
classes.toggle('after', i > s);
classes.toggle('active', i === s);
classes.toggle('previous', i === s-1);
classes.toggle('next', i === s+1);
```

You could also create an object with the keys and conditions, then loop over it to `toggle` them individually:

```
const classes = {
  before: i < s,
  after: i > s,
  active: i === s,
  previous: i === s - 1,
  next: i === s + 1,
};
Object.entries(classes).forEach(([className, condition]) => child.classList.toggle(className, condition));
```

(Note that [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) is an ECMAScript 2017 feature.)

Answer (score 0):

here's one way:

```js
var children2 = Array.from(wrapper.children);
var s = state.state;

//Represent your states as StateName-Predicate map
const States = {
  'active': (i,s) => i===s,
  'before': (i,s) => i<s},
  'previous': (i,s) => i===s-1,
  'next': (i,s) => i===s+1,
  'after': (i,s) => i>s
};


children2.forEach((child, i) => {    
    const classList = child.classList;
    
    //Iterate over all available states
    Object.keys(States).forEach(stateName => {
      //Extract predicate function for a state
      const predicate = States[stateName];
      //If predicate evaluates to true - set class, otherwise - remove it
      classList.toggle(stateName, predicate(i,s) );  
    });
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is one pattern that is extremely repetitive in your code: "if (some condition), add this class". You could probably instead do something like this:

```
var classes = [
  i < s && 'before',
  i > s && 'after',
  i === s && 'active',
  i === s - 1 && 'previous',
  i === s + 1 && 'next'
].filter(x => x)
```

The first part of that code, `var classes = [...]`, creates an array that looks something like `[false, false, 'active', false, false]`, by conditionally adding items. For example, suppose `i` is 3 and `s` is also 3. When JavaScript evaluates `i === s && 'active'`, it sees that `i (3) === s (3)`, so it moves on to the next value, which is `'active'`, and sticks that inside the array. When it evaluates `i === s + 1 && 'next'`, it sees that `i (3)` is *not* the same as `s + 1 (4)`, so it immediately takes false and adds it to the list.

Then, we use `filter` to get rid of those `false` items, so we get an array more like `['active']`. Basically, [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) takes a function and passes each in the array item one by one to it; when the function returns a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, it keeps the item, and otherwise, it removes the item. The function we passed is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions); it just returns the value that is passed to it. You could replace it with `function(x) { return x }` and it would be functionally the same.

(I sometimes use `.filter(Boolean)` instead of `.filter(x => x)`. [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) can be used as a function to convert a value into a boolean (according to the ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) link above) - if you've seen [`!!x` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript) before, it does the same thing. I find `.filter(Boolean)` more syntactic: "keep items that are truthy (like a boolean)". But it's entirely unnecessary because `filter` itself automatically checks if your function's returned value is truthy. So if you use it is just a matter of taste!)

Another option is to just get rid of the unnecessary braces and semicolons, like this:

```
if (i < s) classes.push('before')
if (i > s) classes.push('after')
// ..and so on.
```

It's certainly a bit more verbose, but you might prefer it anyways!